# A non continuous linear map $A:\Bbb{R}[X]\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that $A(P)=P(1).$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, polynomials, normed-spaces

> I have a linear map $A:\Bbb{R}[X]\mapsto \Bbb{R}$ such that $A(P)=P(1)$, for the $p-$norm : $\Vert P\Vert=\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n\vert a_i\vert^p\bigr)^{1/p}$ where $p\in[1,+\infty].$

For the cas where $p=1$ it's continuous (triangle inequality), anyway for the case $p>1$ I would like to prove that is not continuous.

For that I can use the sequential characterization of continuity, if $p=\infty$, the following polynomial $P(X)=1+X+X^2+\cdots+X^n$ works, because $\Vert P\Vert_{\infty}=1$ but $\vert P(1)\vert=1+1+1+\cdots+1=n+1\rightarrow+\infty.$

Anyway, I am stuck for $1<p<\infty$,I get always the same result...

Any idea ?

EDIT : in fact my polynomial works for any $p$.

Comment: note that your polynomials could also be thought as trigonometric polynomials $X = e^{2 i \pi x}$ because of the norm and that the evaluation is at $X = 1$. so you need a Fourier series $f(x) = \sum_{k \ge 0} c_k e^{2 i \pi k x}$ where the $c_k$ are $l^{1+\epsilon}$ but $f(0)$ is unbounded : as Omnomnomnom said choose $c_k = 1/k$, or any series such that $c_k \ge 0$, $\sum (c_k)^p$ converges but not $\sum c_k$

Comment: @user1952009 very nice explanation +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $p\gt1$, consider
$$
a_{n,k}=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\dfrac1{n^{1/p}}&\text{if }1\le k\le n\\
0&\text{if }k\gt n
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n,k}^p\right)^{1/p}
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n\right)^{1/p}\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
while
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n,k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n^{1/p}}\\[6pt]
&=n^{1-\frac1p}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very nice. Thanks! I was sure you will give a short answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Define a sequence of polynomials by
$$
P_n(x)= \frac{1}{\log(\log(n))}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{k+1}x^k
$$

Comment: If I look at $P_n(1)\sim \frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(\log(n))}$ which tends to $\infty$ but we get the same result for the $p-$norm. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: You don't get the same result for the $p$-norm.

Comment: Right, I made a miscalculation. but why $\log(log(n))$ ? Using the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^n 1/k\sim \log(n)$ but that $\sum_{k=0}^n1/k^p$ converges for $p>1$ we don't need this, right ?

Comment: @JeSuis this way, we can say that $P_n\to0$ in norm. However, if you can use the fact that continuous $\iff $ bounded for linear maps, then the $\log\log n$ is indeed unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, for $p>2.$ Let $P_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n j x^j .$  We have $$\|P_n\|^p=\sum_{j=1}^n j^p<\sum_{j=1} ^n\int_j^{j+1}y^p dy=\int_1^{n+1}y^p dy=$$ $$=\frac{(n+1)^{1+p}-1}{1+p}<\frac {(n+1)^{1+p} }{1+p}.$$  $$\text {So }\; \|P_n\|<\frac {(1+n)^{(1+1/p)}}{(1+p)^{1/p}}\;\text { But }\; P_n(1)=(n^2-n)/2.$$

Let $Q_n=P_n/n^{1+2/p}.\;$ Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|Q_n\|=0$ but $\lim_{n\to \infty}Q_n(1)=\infty,$ so $A$ is discontinuous at $0.$

I expect a variation of  this approach should work for $1<p\leq 2.$